# CSS Selector to make the text in an input box bigger

Tags: html, css

I've got a datepicker which displays the selected value in the input box. I want to change the text in the input box using css, but I can't figure out how to select it. Here is my HTML, and the value records the text that I want to change.

```
<input class="datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-required="The FromDate field is required." id="FromDate" name="FromDate" type="date" value="2019-02-01">
```

Comment: you seems to be using datapicker plugin and you want to change a text generated by the plugin. Try to create  a full demo where we can see that text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its current state, you could select the input field by using CSS selectors with attributes along with classes and/or ids , in this case it would be:

```
input[id="FromDate"][class="datepicker"]
{ 
font-size:100px; 
}
```

or using the ID of the element, in your case id="FromDate"

```
 #FromDate
{
 font-size:100px; 
}
```

You may also want to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors .

Comment: Why `[class="datepicker"]` instead of `.datepicker`?

Comment: Hahaha I had set the font-size using the ID before the weekend, then gone back today and tried to change it using the class Monday morning, and couldn't figure out why that wasn't working :) So your answer was correct thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this css :

```
input[type='text'] { font-size: 24px; }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid it's because it's some magical thing that comes 'out-of-the-box' nowadays. Here you can see how it looks [if you're using Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date). [This Medium post](https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/making-input-type-date-complicated-a544fd27c45a) explains a bit about it.

So it's as complicated (and annoying) as styleing the scrollbar; what you're trying. Because all browser are different and that way it's tedious to make and impossible to maintain, - so I wouldn't recommend it.

What I would recommend, if you want to control the styles in the datepicker, then you can implement your own, [using jQuery](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

And just to be clear...

[image: Styling datepicker]

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry this is solved now, my own silly fault I forgot I had given it an ID somewhere else and the font-size on the ID was overriding the font-size I was trying to apply to the class... need another coffee :) Have a good day!